# Run query returned by another query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a create a query which returns a bunch of sql queries , was wondering if those queries can directly be run in one short via a script. Query goes like

```
with abc as (select  a1, a2 from tableX),
xyz as (Select b1,b2 from tableY)
select a1, 'insert into tableZ values col1= '|| abc.a1||''
from abc , xyz
where abc.a1=xyz.b1;
```

so can i run all the inserts returned above in one go

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL if the only non-fixed piece is a data value. Where you would need dynamic SQL is if you are programmatically determining object names (column lists, table names) or query structure (query blocks, joins), etc. Then you can write a cursor in PL/SQL that loops and uses `execute immediate` within the loop to execute your dynamic SQL. But as others have said, your example does not present a case where that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in a PL/SQL block but you do not appear to need to dynamically run your query and, instead, can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` and use a static SQL query:

```sql
INSERT INTO tableZ (col1)
SELECT X.a1
FROM   tableX x
       INNER JOIN tableY y
       ON (x.a1 = y.b1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course with the right syntax

```
CREATE TABLE tableX(a1 int, a2 int)
```

```
CREATE TABLE tableY ( b1 int, b2 int)
```

```
CREATE TABLE tableZ(col1 int)
```

```
insert into tableZ (col1)
with abc as (select  a1, a2 from tableX),
 xyz as (Select b1,b2 from tableY)
  SELECT abc.a1 as Col1
from abc JOIN  xyz ON abc.a1=xyz.b1;
```

```
SELECT * FROM tableZ
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_O2vV2ag)

But you should start using proper `JOIN` they are since 30 years sql standard.

Comment: "Of course with the right syntax" The generated SQL statement is not valid Oracle synax though.

Comment: @MT0 of course it is correct https://dbfiddle.uk/xYZbyz3p

Comment: The *generated* statement isn't valid - `insert into table tableZ values col1= ...`. Plus the OP is asking how to run that generated statement - it would have been less confusing if they'd made that clear and used their real query rather than a mangled substitute *8-)

Comment: ok i missunderstood teh question and corrected it

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you are saying, @nbk, but - why CTEs? You'd get the same result with simpler `insert into tablez select x.a1 from tablex x join tabley y on x.a1 = y.b1;`

Comment: @Littfoot, he posted an abbreviation of his actual maybe very complex queries and want so ro know how he can  combine them, so the CTE are still necessary as we can not know how the basis bhind it actually looks like